# finding non-continuous values under loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, find, continuous

Would you please help me sort this following problem out? I've been stuck here for a while.

I have the data as below. You can see there are 3 loops (column A, B and C) and column D contains the computed values that I want at the index continuous positions.

[image]

However these indexes are not continuous at all. You can see at 3rd-loop (column C), it nicely goes from 1-4 but then the next loop it misses 3...and so on. Consequently, the 2nd-loop doesn't go nicely also. These non-continuous are marked by red number or line...

What I want is the interpolated values in column D in case there are a gap between them, a simple interpolation is already great for me.

Say my loops go from 1:nA, 1:nB and 1:nC. For this very short example, nA=2, nB=3, nC=4 but my true data is up to hundreds...

Comment: This can be many things. Please post your code, especially the loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. But since I have not had any idea on how to solve the problem so I couldnt make up any script.. I'm very sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have in variable `A` the first set of indices, in `B` the second set of indices, in `C` the third set of indices, and in `D` the values. First, you need to put those in order in an array, then interpolate the missing values:

```
%'Calculate the max indices'
nA = max(A);
nB = max(B);
nC = max(C);

%'Calculate the linear indices out of subscripts'
I = nB*nC*(A(:)-1) + nC*(B(:)-1) + C(:);

%'Interpolate the values'
V = interp1(I, D(:), transpose(1:nA*nB*nC), 'linear');
```

You can try fancier interpolation methods by consulting the help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: wow.... thank you, thank you very much. The problem is solved !!
Your idea of getting the I is genius !! Thank you thank you !!